# SQL view, how to append results from tableB with the results from tableA

Tags: sql-server, view

I am using SQL server 2012. I would like to generate a sql view where I got all records from tableA. And below these results I would like to have the results from tableB. There are no relations between these 2 tables. The columns are also differant. Here is an example:

```
tableA:                       tableB:

+-------------------------+   +--------------------------------+
| Name                        | Year
---------------------------   +---------------------------------
| A    |                      | 2000    |
| B    |                      | 2001    |
| C    |                      | 2002    |
```

I would like to have results like this:

```
 +-------------------------+   
    | Name | Year                   
    ------------------------
    | A    |                   
    | C    |
    | D    |
    |      | 2000
    |      | 2001
    |      | 2002
```

How can I realize this? I see only joins, union solutions, but they dont work for me because I dont have some relation between these 2 tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte1(Name, Year) as ( select Name, null as year from tablea),
cte2(Name, Year) as (select NULL as Name, year from tableb)
Select Name, Year from CTE1
UNION ALL
select Name, Year from CTE2
```

This should work, didn't read the question properly last answer :)

Comment: You're missing `as` in second cte.

Comment: Yeah written without developper :p that's better now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted them randonly side by side you could use an adhoc ID value. If there are different numbers in each table then some will appear at the end without a partner.

```
with cte1 as
(
 select a1.name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a1.name) as ID from a1
),
cte2 as
(
select c1.theyear, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by c1.theyear) as ID from c1
)
select cte1.name, cte2.theyear
from cte1
left outer join cte2 on cte1.id = cte2.id
```